# Sorting MySQL query with non-unique values

Tags: mysql

I want to create a navigation with next and previous buttons and i want to sort the order by popularly of the post. popularity column is made with views + likes

```
Post_id | post_popularity
1       | 25    
2       | 10
3       | 30
4       | 10
5       | 45
```

So I try adding the query

```
//Previous
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_live=1 and post_popularity>$post_popularity ORDER BY post_popularity ASC LIMIT 1

//Next
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_live=1 and post_popularity<$post_popularity ORDER BY post_popularity DESC LIMIT 1
```

This seems to loop most of the posts and then i try

```
//Previous
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_live=1 and (post_popularity > $post_popularity) OR (post_popularity = $post_popularity AND post_id < $post_id) ASC LIMIT 1

//Next
 SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_live=1 and (post_popularity < $post_popularity) OR (post_popularity = $post_popularity AND post_id > $post_id) ASC LIMIT 1
```

This seems to do the same thing. Looping most of the posts. Any pointers on how to archive this query. I greatly appropriate your help.

Comment: Try to use
//Previous

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_live=1 AND post_popularity >= $post_popularity AND post_id != $post_id ASC ORDER BY post_popularity, post_id LIMIT 1`

//Next

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_live=1 AND post_popularity <= $post_popularity AND post_id != $post_id ASC ORDER BY post_popularity, post_id LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

I would select the current, the previous and the next post with one query. In this way you have to execute less queries to load all your data needed to display one site.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_live=1 ORDER BY post_popularity ASC LIMIT 3 offset $index_of_current_post_minus_one;
```

for the first post the `$index_of_current_post_minus_one` is `0`. You get 3 results the first ist the current item the second is next and the third can be ignored. If you hit your next button you increment your counter `$index_of_current_post_minus_one` becomes `0` (index of the displayed post is 1 but you always substract 1). From now on it becomes straight forward. This first result row ist your previous , the second your current and the third your next. clicking next again the `$index_of_current_post_minus_one` becomes `1`and so on.

In addition you should create an index on your table pre-sorting your posts on their popularity so the rows must not be sorted for every query:

```
alter table post add index pop_live(post_popularity, post_live);
```